How to find records where a JSON value exists?
I'm using Manticore Search with the official PHP library. I have an index of people with a list of reasons our system will not accept them ("violations"). The index is created like this:
[
    'name' => ['type' => 'text'],
    'violations' => ['type' => 'json']
    // Other irrelevant fields
]

The index also has the following config options:
'expand_keywords' => '1',
'index_exact_words' => '1',
'min_prefix_len' => '0',
'min_infix_len' => '2',

The violations JSON field stores data like this:
{
    "keys":["age"],
    "messages":{"age":"This person is too young"}
}

The data is structured this way in the JSON so I can output some plain text explanations on screen, as well as storing the keys for search purposes, but can be changed if required.
I can manually search for records using the Manticore MySQL interface as follows:
SELECT *, ANY(x = 'age' FOR x in violations.keys) cond FROM people WHERE cond=1;

However, I can't see a way to replicate this with the PHP search class, e.g.
$search->filter('violations', 'in', ['age'];

Does any mechanism exist in the PHP library to allow searching where a JSON value is present, or do I need to fall back to the SQL mode? I'd prefer to avoid this if possible, as it complicates some of the other filters I have to add to the query, depending on other conditions in the application.

Try this:
$search->expression('contains_age', "ANY(x = 'age' FOR x in violations.keys)");
$search->filter('contains_age', 1);


Why "try this"? What does your code do? Why should it work? Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.

Hi, please read how to answer
